# Speech recognition , match the two voices

Tags: android

My question is that, in my application i want to use a voice recognition in which a user voice is recorded to a instrumental sound and a result is formed through a graph or a score count that much your voice is correct to a actual voice ... my request is similar to a recognition of speech

Comment: could you please provide your code?

Answer (score 1):

Speech Recogniser will not to recognise voice. You have to use DSP technology. i don't think you can achieve this within the device itself. You can save your audio (using something like Audio Record in Android) and then send it to a server. in the server side you can run a speaker recognition program. ALIZE is a quite popular open source tool for this.

Comment: `Speech Recogniser will not to recognise speech.` It actually *will* recognize **speech**. It won't recognize **voices**.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is speaker recognition.

You can [Microsoft Speaker Recognition Service](https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/speaker-recognition-api). It allows you to do one of two tasks:

- Speaker Verification: Verification of the identity of a single speaker (this is what you need in your scenario).
- Speaker Identification: Recognizing which speaker is talking from a group of speakers.

The starting point is having a look at [the documentation](https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/speaker-recognition-api/documentation), and choosing one of [the sample apps or SDKs](https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/SDK-Sample?api=speaker%20recognition) to use.